# Screen scraping with htmlAgilityPack and XPath

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

[This question has a relative that lives at: [Selective screen scraping with HTMLAgilityPack and XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404839/selective-screen-scraping-with-htmlagilitypack-and-xpath) ]

I have some HTML to parse which has general appearance as follow:

```
...
<tr>
<td><a href="" title="">Text Data here (1)</a></td>
<td>Text Data here(2)</td>
<td>Text Data here(3)</td>
<td>Text Data here(4)</td>
<td>Text Data here(5)</td>
<td>Text Data here(6)</td>
<td><a href="link here {1}" class="image"><img alt="" src="" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="" title="">Text Data here (1)</a></td>
<td>Text Data here(2)</td>
<td>Text Data here(3)</td>
<td>Text Data here(4)</td>
<td>Text Data here(5)</td>
<td>Text Data here(6)</td>
<td><a href="link here {1}" class="image"><img alt="" src="" /></a></td>
</tr>
...
```

I am looking for a way where I can parse it down in meaningful chunks like this:

(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), {1}`CRLF`
(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), {1}`CRLF`
and so on

I have tried two ways:
way 1:

```
var dataList = currentDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr")
                .Select
                 (
                  tr => tr.Descendants("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToList()
                 ).ToList();
```

which fetches me the inner text of the `td`s, but fails to fetch the link {1}. Here, a list is created which contains a lot of lists. I can manage it using nested foreach.

way 2:

```
var dataList = currentDoc.DocumentNode
               .SelectNodes("//tr//td//text()|//tr//td//a//@href");
```

which does get me the link {1} and all data but it becomes unorganized. Here, all the data is present in big chunk. Since, the data in one `tr` is relative, I now loose that relation.

So, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The (x) data in the TD and the {x} data in the HREF are different, so you need two piece of code to get it. What do you need exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query selects `a` element with non-empty `href` attribute from each cell. If there is no such element, then inner text of cell is used:

```
var dataList = 
     currentDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr")
               .Select(tr => from td in tr.Descendants("td")
                             let a = td.SelectSingleNode("a[@href!='']")
                             select a == null ? td.InnerText : 
                                                a.Attributes["href"].Value);
```

Feel free to add `ToList()` calls.

Comment: `var dataList =
     currentDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr")
               .Select(tr => from td in tr.Descendants("td")
                             let a = td.SelectSingleNode("a[starts-with(@class,'image')]")
                             select a == null ? td.InnerText :
                                                a.Attributes["href"].Value);` does it. It's quirky. But works. Thanks.

Comment: any idea if I wanted to scrap data selectively? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404839/selective-screen-scraping-with-htmlagilitypack-and-xpath

Comment: @AnubhavSaini hold on, I'll check